# get the url of the visited page using a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the actual url of the visited page using a bookmarklet?

The idea is to click on a bookmark and the script in the bookmark returns the url.

This was a function available in Plex some time ago as a "watch later" feature to save a playlist. So it is working, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
javascript:(()=>{console.log(location.href);})();
```

`location.href` holds the current URL string.

---

**Edit** in response to question in comment

> Any idea how I can send it to php like this: `script.php?url=this_url`
>
> or
>
> How can I send the current URL as search parameter value to another URL?

Let's say you want to send it to `https://example.com?script.php?url=` `<the current URL>`. You'd just set `location.href` to the new URL and use `encodeURI` to encode the current URL (from `location.href`). (Kind of meta, right?) This is what that would look like:

```js
javascript:(()=>{location.href=`https://example.com/script.php?url=${encodeURI(location.href)}`;})();
```

In fact, I'll make it even easier for you. Just expand and run the code snippet below, and you can input the URL that you want to send it to (e.g. `https://example.com/script?url=`) and you'll see the JavaScript bookmarklet update as you type.

```js
(() => {
  'use strict';

  const copyTextToClipboard = text => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const fallback = text => {
      const textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
      textArea.value = text;
      textArea.style.position='fixed';
      document.body.appendChild(textArea);
      textArea.focus();
      textArea.select();
      try {
        const successful = document.execCommand('copy');
        successful
          ? resolve(true)
          : reject(new Error('"document.execCommand(\'copy\')" failed'));
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      finally {
        document.body.removeChild(textArea);
      }
    };
  
    if (!navigator.clipboard) {
      fallback(text);
      return;
    }
    try {
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
      resolve(true);
    }
    catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });

  const input = document.getElementById('input');
  const output = document.getElementById('output');
  const copyButton = document.getElementById('copy');

  const makeBookmarklet = string =>
    `javascript:(()=>{location.href=\`${string}\${encodeURI(location.href)}\`;})();`;

  const updateOutput = ev => {
    output.textContent = makeBookmarklet(ev.target.value.trim());
  };

  const placeholder = 'https://example.com/script.php?url=';
  input.placeholder = placeholder;
  output.textContent = makeBookmarklet(placeholder);
  input.addEventListener('input', updateOutput);
  copyButton.addEventListener('click', () => copyTextToClipboard(output.textContent));
})();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#input,
#output,
#copy {
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#input {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#output {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 1em;
}

#copy {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

pre {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  /* height: 5em; */
  margin: 1em 0 0.5em;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="input" type="text" />
  <pre><code id="output"></code></pre>
  <div><button id="copy">Copy bookmarklet</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it would be that easy. :) Any idea how I can send it to php like this: script.php?url=this_url

Comment: That's amazing thank you so much. One more thing, is it possible to use Basic Authentication that way?

Comment: @davinci Not in a general way. Basic Authentication is a header value in the http request, which is automatically sent by your browser. This only changes the URL of your browser. It might be possible to complete a fetch request in a bookmarklet, but I wouldn't advise storing plaintext credentials in a bookmark like that. You might also run into CORS issues, etc.